# Angular 2: how control <video> from component

Tags: angular

I'm try working with Angular 2, but freeze on working on HTML 5 video. In manual I found, that can use in template:

```ts
<video #videoplayer></video>
```

This should create local variable "videoplayer" that provides access to the video element. It is possible get it from component, for example:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: '<some>',
    template: '<video #videoplayer></video>'
})

export class SomeComponent {

   public videoplayer; // How can I got element object here?

   play() { // I need work with <video> in Component
      this.videoplayer.play();
   }
}
```

Thank you for help, I try @Host it or use it like @Input but still don't work as I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```ts
@ViewChild('videoplayer') videoPlayer;
```

And the in `ngAfterViewInit()` you should be able to access it.

Alternatively you can just bind to properties

```ts
<video [someProp]="someField"></video>
```

and events

```ts
<video (someEvent)="someHandler($event)"></video>
```